# Functions that return another function in Swift

Tags: swift, function, return

Ola,

Let's say that there is a function named `fnOuter(name:String, mks:Double...)`. I want this function to return another function which I could separately write like `fnInner(msg:String)->(String, Double, Double, Character)`. How one could achieve this?
I am a newbie to Swift and tried out the following. But ultimately it ends up with `function 'std' was used as a property; add () to call it` thrown by the Swift compiler. What am I doing wrong here? How could I fix this? Or is this even possible?

```
func fnRetFn(name:String, mks:Double...) -> (() -> ((String, Double, Double, Character))){
    var msg = "Hello " + String(name) + "!"

    func calculate() -> (String, Double, Double, Character){
        var total:Double = 0.0
        var i: Double = 0.0
        for mk in mks{
            total += mk
            i += 1
        }

        var avg = total / i

        var grd : Character
        if avg >= 75.0{
            grd = "A"
        }

        else if avg >= 55.0{
            grd = "B"
        }

        else{
            grd = "F"
        } 

        return (msg, total, avg, grd)
    }

    return calculate
}

var outputFn = fnRetFn(name:"Mike", mks:75.3, 87.2)
var std = outputFn
print("\(std.0)")
print("\(std.1)")
print("\(std.2)")
print("\(std.3)")
```

**Edit 1**
Please note that the fnInner(msg:String) should return a **tuple, not another function**.

Comment: Add parentheses to actually *call* the function: `var std = outputFn()`, as the compiler suggests.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the prompt response. The thing is, I want fnInner() to return a tuple, not a function. Pardon me that this was not clear in the initial question.

Comment: I am aware of that, and it does not change what I said above. – Did you try it?

Comment: Yup. That works. I have tried it previously. What I can't figure out is why do I have to call it? Why isn't it accessible like we do when we return a tuple instead of a function (i.e. std.0 instead of std().0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
var outputFn = fnRetFn(name:"Mike", mks:75.3, 87.2)
var std = outputFn
```

both `outputFn` and `std` are references to the same *function* which
was returned by `fnRetFn(...)`:

```
print(std) // (Function)
```

To *call* the function you'll have to append the argument list
in parentheses. For a function taking no arguments that is the
empty list `()`:

```
var outputFn = fnRetFn(name:"Mike", mks:75.3, 87.2)
var std = outputFn()
```

And now `std` is the *tuple* returned from calling the "inner" function:

```
print(std) // ("Hello Mike!", 162.5, 81.25, "A")
print(std.0, std.1, std.2, std.3) // Hello Mike! 162.5 81.25 A
```

(Unrelated to your problem, but note that both variables should be *constants* declared with `let`.)

Comment: Thank you @MartinR. I figured out the mistake I have done. I have missed to put on parenthesis in the `outputFn()` call. I realized it only when I read up to the second line of your answer. Thanks again for enlightening me. You saved my day... :)

Comment: @MartinR "Unrelated to your problem, but note that both variables should be constants declared with let" almost the best part of it :)